# urls amigavel para diversas pastas

Tags: php, htaccess, url, url-amigável

Tenho essas urls, estou usando subpastas, mas o htaccess vai ficar na raiz

PASTA MEDICO

quando a pessoa faz login para redirecionamento aparece na url ?id=1 sem o index

```
laudar.php?id=1
relatoriolaudos.php?id=1
listalaudos.php?id=1
imprimir.php?id=1&idlaudo=1
editarlaudo.php?id=1&idlaudo=1
bloqueado.php?id=1&idlaudo=1&idusuario=1&nivelu=1&status=1
editardados.php?id=1
```

PASTA LOGIN

```
index.php
senhaincorreta.php
sair.php
mensagem.php
```

PASTA ADMINISTRADOR

quando a pessoa faz login para redirecionamento aparece na url ?id=1 sem o index

```
cadastrodemedicos.php?id=1
cadastrodedigitador.php?id=1
cadastroCategoria.php?id=1
cadastrodeexames.php?id=1
cadastrodeadministrador.php?id=1
cadastrodeadministrador.php?id=1



pesquisademedicos.php?id=1
pesquisadedigitador.php?id=1
pesquisaCategoria.php?id=1
pesquisadeexames.php?id=1
pesquisadeadministrador.php?id=1

exibeadmin.php?id=1&idadmin=1
exibemedico.php?id=1&idmedico=1
exibedigitador.php?id=1&iddigitador=1
pesquisaCategoria.php?id=1
exibetipo.php?id=1&idtipo=5


editaradmin.php?id=1&idadmin=1
editarmedico.php?id=1&idmedico=1
editardigitador.php?id=1&iddigitador=1
editarcategoria.php?id=1&idcategoria=2
```

PASTA DIGITADOR

quando a pessoa faz login para redirecionamento aparece na url `?id=1` sem o index

```
digitando.php?id=2
digitar.php?id=2&idlaudo=4
revisao.php?id=2
imprimir.php?id=2&idlaudo=1
```

Comment: Você vai ter que reajustar todos os arquivos para conseguir.

Comment: Esse ?id=1, é o idUsuario? Porque não registra na session o id deste usuário @DéboraGonçalves

Answer (score 0):

Você pode trabalhar seu htaccess dessa forma:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Posteriormente, poderá usar também o `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` para buscar sua URL, com base nisso, trabalhar as internas uma a uma...

E você deverá passar o `idUsuario` por `session` para que não seja possível trocá-lo via `URL`.

Este seria um exemplo prático:

```
// Recupera a URL da requisição e seus parâmetros, separando em um vetor dividido pelo caracter "/"
$geturl = explode( "/", str_replace( strrchr( $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "?" ), "", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] ) );
array_shift( $geturl );

// Considera o primeiro parâmetro como o arquivo php
$tipo = $geturl[0];

// Se o arquivo existir, inclui na página. Caso contrário, devemos redirecionar o usuário para uma
// tela amigável de error 404
if ( is_file( "$tipo.php" ) )
{
    include "$tipo.php";
}
else
{
    echo "Página não encontrada";   
}
```

Outra opção é você dar uma olhada nesse artigo: http://php.eduardokraus.com/trabalhando-com-url-amigavel-no-php